# CSS auto height on second text line with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I have this scenario where I should expect this layout:

[image]

using this CSS:

```
.row_line { 
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* height: 32px !important; */
    height: 50px !important;
    /* border: 1px solid white;  */
    padding-bottom: 10px !important;
}
/*
.row_line :first-child { width: 10%; }
.row_line :second-child, .row_service :third-child  { width: 58%; }
*/
.first_column_icon { 
    flex: 0 0 100%;     
    width: 7% !important;
    min-width: 5% !important;
    /* border: 1px solid red;  */
}
.first_column_icon img { height: 36px !important; }
.second_column_row_text, .third_column_row_text { 
    flex: 0 0 50%; 
    width: 60% !important;
    min-width: 50% !important;
    padding-top: 0; 
    padding-bottom: 0;
    /* border: 1px solid yellow;  */
}
.third_column_row_text { 
    font-size: 10px !important; 
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
.fourth_column_buttons_and_label { 
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    width: 30% !important;
    min-width: 25% !important;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    /* border: 1px solid blue; */
}
```

On desktop and on some mobiles it expects as like as in the picture above but on some mobile that .second_column_row_text when having a long text doesn't auto height to stay under first row text and goes right to the first row as in the picture below:

[image]

How I can keep that second row text below the first row making some height overflow to the entire box correctly with flexbox? Thanks a lot in advance to all! Cheers! :-)

**EDIT:**

Adding `align-items: stretch;` as @Mohsen suggested, plus also reactivating `border` to check its extension I obtain this result:

[image]

without showing `border` I obtain this result where second row is at right side of first row and buttons+label disappears from the view:

[image]

the html where applied is:

```
<li class='li_row'>
    <div class='row_line'>
        <div class='first_column_icon'>
            <img src='...' id='check_01' />         
        </div>
        <div class='second_column_row_text'><label>some text some text</label></div>
        <div class='third_column_row_text'><label>some description some description some description</label></div>
        <div class='fourth_column_buttons_and_label'>
            <div class='wrapper_right'>
                <button id='...' class='...'></button>
                <div class='...';>
                    <span id='...' maxlenght='99' class='...'>0</span>
                    <input type='text' id='...' maxlenght='99' class='...' value='0' readonly style='visibility: hidden' />
                </div>
                <button id='...' class='...'></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

maybe I missed something to consider implementing that html and using flexbox?...

**EDIT 2:**

As @Retroactives.com said, I removed that `height: 55px !important;` so should be auto height based on contents but I got disappeared that center column with those two rows and last column:

[image]

Adding a parent `<div class='center_column'>` , on mobile the second row remains under first one but it doesn't word wrap even if I have in CSS `word-wrap: break-word; overflow-wrap: break-word;` and no fixed height so it could overflow some space to show the rest of the text in second row...practically modified that part with those two rows as:

some text some text
    some description some description some description

adding in CSS the center_column:

```
.center_column {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    width: 60%;
    min-width: 60%;
    /* border: 1px dotted yellow;  */
}
.second_column_row_text, .third_column_row_text { 
    flex: 0 0 50%; 
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 0; 
    padding-bottom: 0;
    /* border: 1px dotted white; */
}
.third_column_row_text { 
    font-size: 11px; 
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;  
}
```

Comment: There should be no maxlength here and it is spelled wrong in both places <span id='...' maxlenght='99' class='...'>0</span>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I solved adding in second row a "more..." link which would toggle a 100%'s width div under row_line that would show all details needed... Thanks anyway @Mohsen and @Retroactives.com !!!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have height: 50px !important; in .row_line?

What are you expecting flex-wrap: wrap; to do?

This

```html
<div class='second_column_row_text'><label>some text some text</label></div>
<div class='third_column_row_text'><label>some description some description some description</label></div>
```

Should be

```html
<div>
       <div class='second_column_row_text'><label>some text some text</label></div>
        <div class='third_column_row_text'><label>some description some description some description</label></div>
</div>
```

If you do not wrap the second_column_row_text and  third_column_row_text  with a div, they become flex items and do exactly what you told them to do with flex-wrap: wrap;

Comment: thanks for your answer @Retroactives.com , I tried including those two rows in a center_column div but the longest text row doesn't make its div to overflow some height to show word-wrapped text ... I re-edited my post adding modifies on CSS to include text rows in div column...